# Getting Already Active Instance of Excel in MS JScript

Tags: c#, msdn, excel-interop, jscript, activexobject

I'm struggling a bit trying to translate some C# code I wrote a while back into JScript.  In the long run I need to open an Excel Workbook, or (if it's already open) bring it to the front.  Unlike C#, JScript relies on a shoddy `ActiveXObject` to get a handle on the Excel application:

```
var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
```

Once you've grabbed the object the API is pretty similar across all languages that the MSDN applies to.  However, **using the `ActiveXObject` seems to create an entirely new instance of Excel**.

If I were to use the following code:

```
var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
alert(Excel.ActiveSheet === null); // assume alert works as it does in Javascript
```

and Excel were already open, the alert would come back as `true`.  Furthermore, any variables set with `new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application")` that haven't been picked up by garbage collection cause a new EXCEL.EXE process to appear:

[image]

Needless to say, all of this keeps me from checking if a workbook is already open, and subsequently causes an ugly "would you like to open this read-only" warning to appear.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: If your only concern is the ugly "would you like to open this read-only" warning, you can just open the workbook as read-only.

Comment: @DanielCook Ah, the issue being is that it needs to be editable and in focus.  Opening as read-only while the document is already open actually opens up a second copy of the workbook (the first already editable, and the second read-only).  Otherwise that (or just suppressing warnings) would be excellent solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to MSDN, you can use [the `GetObject` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7tf9xwsc%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) from JScript.

```
var Excel = GetObject(null, "Excel.Application");
```

Comment: The OP is asking about JScript not Javascript. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ebdktb00(v=vs.100).aspx) would be a more appropriate reference. I'm not sure if the syntax is different or not...

Comment: I didn't realise anyone was still using JScript.NET! Nice to see the documentation is up to the usual standard - both parameters are listed as "required", the examples show calls passing just the `pathname` parameter, and the comments mention "if `pathname` is omitted...". :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if your code is right or not because I'm unwilling to test it and I felt that the documentation wasn't quite clear. >.> But I'll upvote anyway because I'm sure this is useful. :)

Comment: Ha, yeah, there's still some legacy stuff out there in the wings.  I'll test these approaches out right away.  Thanks and BRB.

Comment: @DanielCook RichardDeeming; Alright, so I can definitely get the object if I give it just a path to the file.  If I try to pass it an application class either by itself, or with a path, it fails (class name or file name not found).  Once I have the object via path, it still doesn't seem to have the same members as my old `ActiveXObject`.  Using `alert(Excel.ActiveSheet === null);` results in false (yay!) but trying to use other functionality like `Excel.Visible = true` fail ("Object doesn't support this property or method").

Comment: After a lot of finangaling (real word) I've sort of gotten it working using GetObject. Unfortunately it appears that as soon as the script completes (and the object is picked up by garbage collection) Excel shuts down. I'm going to open up another question for that (it's a different issue). I've added the additional code to your answer with an edit.  I also updated the link to point to the JScript.NET doc.

Comment: @SandyGifford: I don't see your edit. Did you save the changes?

Comment: I did.  It said the edit was awaiting approval.  I don't see that message anymore, though

Comment: @SandyGifford: Strange. I haven't seen any notification of a pending edit, and there's no sign of your changes.

Comment: Maybe someone rejected them before you got the notification.

Comment: @SandyGifford: That would be quite rude. Also, I think it's supposed to take three "reject" votes for an edit to be rejected.